# Angularjs How to use Codeigniter functions in partials?

Tags: angularjs, function, codeigniter, partials

Is there any chance to use Codeigniter function in Angularjs partials? (form_open, close, etc)

Comment: Please give us more information on what you are trying to do? Angularjs have it's own controllers and it gets integrated with the HTML..

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible to make for example form using Codeigniter function form_open form_input form_hidden or I need to use just html?

Comment: How you will be using codeigniter ? for web services only ? who will handle routing ? angular or codeigniter?

Comment: Routing - angular.
Its my folder structure
http://imgur.com/JTh2f0X

It's better to use php framework just for backend? (db operations)